# Prove the nonzero postive operator $P$ has 1 dimensional range

Tags: linear-algebra, positive-semidefinite

> Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional complex inner product space, and let $P \in L(V)$ be a non-zero positive operator with the property that for all positive operators $Q, R$ such that $P = Q+R$, there
> is a real number $0 \le r \le 1$ such that $Q = r P$. Prove that $\dim \text{range} P = 1$.

I don't have any ideas about how to approach this problem. I tried to use a complex spectral theorem, but I failed. Then I also noticed that if $Q+R=P$ and $Q, R$ are positive, this means that $P=rP+R$ which makes $R=(1-r)P$. Thus, I think this means that $P$ can only be rewritten as $(1-r)P+rP$ and it can't be rewritten as the sum of other positive operators. This is also the given information that I'm not able to use in my proof.

Thus, any help on this? Thank!

Comment: Do these operators have to be positive definite? or is positive semidefinite OK?

Comment: Just positive semidefinite, or I should say operators P has properties that it is self-adjoint and $\langle Pv,v\rangle \geq 0$. Similarly for R and Q

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** I think it is easiest to prove this statement by contrapositive. If $P$ is a positive operator with range of dimension $2$ or greater, use the spectral theorem to construct positive operators $Q,R$ such that $Q + R = P$ but $Q$ and $R$ are not multiples of each other (in fact, we can select such operators $Q,R$ so that $QR = 0$).

Comment: For example, I let dim range P =2. Then By spectral theorem, on the basis $(e_1,\cdots,e_n)$ $P$ is diagonalized. Then I suppose $Pe_1=\lambda_1,Pe_2=\lambda_2e_2$ with $\lambda_1,\lambda_2>0$. Then $Pe_j=0$ for $j=3,\cdots,n$. Then I can construct $A$ and $B$. For $Ae_1=\lambda_1e_1$ others are 0, and $Be_2=\lambda_2$ and others are zero. By the matrix of $A,B$, they are self-adjoint. For $v=a_1e_1+\cdots+a_ne_n$, $\langle Av,v\rangle\geq 0$. Thus A,B are positive. But by the matrix of A,B, none of them is rP or (1-r)P since they have different range. Is this idea right?

Comment: @Yink That’s exactly the idea

Answer (score 1):

If $P$ is to have rank $1$, then there must be $x,y\in V$ such that $P =\langle\cdot,x\rangle y$, with positivity of $P$ reading as $$\langle Pv,v\rangle = \langle \langle v,x\rangle y, v\rangle = \langle v,x\rangle \langle v,y\rangle \geq 0$$for all $v\in V$. Choosing $v=x$ and $v=y$ leads to $\langle x,y\rangle \geq 0$. This last condition is indeed enough to ensure that $\langle\cdot,x\rangle y$ is positive, as it spectrum is $\{\langle x,y\rangle ,0\}$ (with $0$ having multiplicity $\dim V - 1$, coming from $x^\perp$) Let's reverse engineer what $x$ and $y$ must be.

Since $P\neq 0$ by assumption, there is a non-zero $y$ in the range of $P$. Choose $x_1\in V$ with $\langle x_1,y\rangle \geq 0$ small enough so that $\langle \cdot, x_1\rangle y$ and $P - \langle\cdot,x_1\rangle y$ are *both* still positive. Then writing $$P = \langle \cdot, x_1\rangle y + (P-\langle\cdot,x_1\rangle y)$$yields $0\leq r \leq 1$ such that $P - \langle\cdot,x_1\rangle y = r\langle\cdot,x_1\rangle y$. Then set $x = (1+r)x_1$ and we're done.